# Visual block mode and vim surround?

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

Let's say I have text like this,

```
SPAC     SPAC - Specific-Purpose Committee Campaign Finance Report 
SPAC-SS  SPAC-SS - Specific-Purpose Committee Special Session Report          
SPAC-T   SPAC-T -  PAC Special Pre-election (Telegram) Report of Contributions
```

Now how would I use vim-surround to surround to get,

```
'SPAC'     SPAC - Specific-Purpose Committee Campaign Finance Report 
'SPAC-SS'  SPAC-SS - Specific-Purpose Committee Special Session Report          
'SPAC-T'   SPAC-T -  PAC Special Pre-election (Telegram) Report of Contributions
```

I can use block surround entering visual-block mode with <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, making the selection and using `S'`, but I get

```
'SPAC    ' SPAC - Specific-Purpose Committee Campaign Finance Report 
'SPAC-SS ' SPAC-SS - Specific-Purpose Committee Special Session Report          
'SPAC-T  ' SPAC-T -  PAC Special Pre-election (Telegram) Report of Contributions
```

Ideally, I would have a better method that would do inner word. What would work in this situation, trimming the whitespace from both sides of the collection?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the best way to do what you want is to use a substitution command:

```
:'<,'>s/[^ ]\+/'\0'
```

Which is decomposed like this:

```
'<,'>                  the range of lines you want to treat (you could use % is you want to change all the lines of the buffer, or use line numbers e.g. 1,10)
     s/                the substitution command
       [^ ]\+          all the characters until the first white space
             /
              '\0'     \0 is what you matched before and it is surrounded by quotes.
```

---

If you really want to use vim-surround you could use a macro. First empty your register with `qaq`, then on the first line use:

```
qa0ysW'jq
```

to do the following:

```
qa           record a macro in the register a
  0          move to the beginning of the line
   ysW'      surround the word with simple quotes
       j     move one line down
        q    stop recording
```

You can then use `10@a` to execute the macro 10 ten times (so on the ten next lines)

---

Note that even with a macro you don't need the surround plugin:

```
qaI'<Esc>Ea'jq
```

Which means:

```
qa               record the macro
  I'             insert a quote at the beginning of the line
    <Esc>        exist insert mode
         E       go to the end of the first word
          a'     insert a quote after the word
            j    go down one line
             q   stop recording
```

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, I would have a better method that would do inner word.

You can do that with `:normal`.

```
:%norm ysiW'
```

I assume you want an inner WORD not word.

You can also visually select the lines and then do:

```
:norm ysiW'
```

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h :range
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to care what I select it only ever quotes the first WORD.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, This is using `:normal` with a visual range, i.e. `:'<,'>norm`. This means that it is going to run the normal commands `ysiW'` on each line in that range.  So it will surround the first word in each line in the visual selection with single quotes. See `:h :norm`, `:h '<`, and `:h v_:` for more information

Comment: I understand, but the example only used the first column because I wasn't aware that answers would presume I wanted *just* the first column. See this as a follow up. https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17593/5078

Comment: Sadly there is no native method to "run command on a visual block". Your best bet would be to do a substitution, a macro, or maybe using `:!` & awk. Surround does try to do different things based on the visual mode, but as you stated it does not help. You could also adjust your `:normal` like so `:execute "normal ".vertcol("'<")."\<bar>ysiW'" to take account for the column position of your visual block.